# New drag and drop lightning control in Attachments

Tags: lightning-aura-components, attachment, files

I'm trying to figure out if this:

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_files_related_list_drag.htm

Is available as a lightning component to use in your own lightning components or apps?

I did find this:
https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/file-selector/

But that's just the styling for the component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not available in this release as a custom component; it only applies to the standard Files related list. However, Winter '18 provides a new `lightning:fileUpload` element that will be available for your custom components. You can read more about it in the [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_lc_components.htm).

Comment: Nice! I just read the Winter '18 release notes and was going to answer this myself.